# How to get the reach and frequency fields using python API call from LinkedIn campagins

Tags: linkedin-api, linkedin-j

API:
[https://api.linkedin.com/v2/adAnalyticsV2?q=analytics&pivot=CAMPAIGN&timeGranularity=DAILY&dateRange.start.day=1&dateRange.start.month=7&dateRange.start.year=2023&dateRange.end.day=4&dateRange.end.month=8&dateRange.end.year=2023&campaigns=urn:li:sponsoredCampaign:{}&fields=likes,clicks,impressions,totalEngagements,opens,likes,pivotValues,reactions,registrations,talentLeads](https://api.linkedin.com/v2/adAnalyticsV2?q=analytics&pivot=CAMPAIGN&timeGranularity=DAILY&dateRange.start.day=1&dateRange.start.month=7&dateRange.start.year=2023&dateRange.end.day=4&dateRange.end.month=8&dateRange.end.year=2023&campaigns=urn:li:sponsoredCampaign:%7B%7D&fields=likes,clicks,impressions,totalEngagements,opens,likes,pivotValues,reactions,registrations,talentLeads)

I was able to fetch all the fields those are mentioned in the above API. But, if I try to get reach, frequency and leads fields it is throwing an error.
The same fields we can see in the Linkedin Campaign manager exported reports.

Error Content:

```
{
    "serviceErrorCode": 100,
    "message": "not enough permissions to access field reach for GET-analytics /adAnalyticsV2",
    "status": 403
}
```

Is there any way to fetch the LinkedIn Campaign export report using Python API call. Or, the solution to resolve the above problem.

https://api.linkedin.com/v2/adAnalyticsV2?q=statistics&pivots=CAMPAIGN&timeGranularity=DAILY&dateRange.start.day=1&dateRange.start.month=7&dateRange.start.year=2023&dateRange.end.day=4&dateRange.end.month=8&dateRange.end.year=2023&campaigns=urn:li:sponsoredCampaign:228550443&fields=likes,clicks,impressions,totalEngagements,opens,likes,pivotValues

I tried using another API, it is also throwing the same error.

```
{
    "serviceErrorCode": 100,
    "message": "not enough permissions to access field reach for GET-statistics /adAnalyticsV2",
    "status": 403
}
```